# PHP message: PHP Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time after PHP 7 Upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, session, mariadb, session-cookies

In my PHP application users are able to log in but new users are not able to register due to the following error after PHP 7 upgrade.
The error is : `PHP message: PHP Warning:  ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in`
I am hosting my server on Cloudways. Could anyone help me with that. I am trying to find the solution for two days.

Functions.php code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1209600); 
// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(1209600);

function logged_in () {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['usnm']) || !empty($_COOKIE['usnm']) && isset($_COOKIE['usid']) || !empty($_COOKIE['usid'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['usid'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['usnm'];
        return true;
         setcookie("usnm",$mobile, time() + (10 * 14 * 24 * 60 * 60));
         setcookie("usid",$_SESSION['user_id'], time() + (10 * 14 * 24 * 60 * 60));
          setcookie("usnm",$user['mobile'], time() + (10 * 14 * 24 * 60 * 60));
         setcookie("usid",$user['userid'], time() + (10 * 14 * 24 * 60 * 60));

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function redirect_to ($url) {
    @header("Location: {$url}");
}
?>
```

Comment: So SWAP line 1 and line 2 .... and _BOB's Yer proverbial male relative on your fathers side_

Comment: And probably place line 3 above the `session start()` as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did as you said but its not working. it shows the error' PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user_id ' and automatically redirect to index page

Comment: THats a completely different error

Comment: I dont see how an upgrade to PHP7 caused the login function to fail, that can never have worked. When you run a `return` control is imediately returned to the calling line. So the lines of code AFTER a return will never get run

Comment: You also seem to be duplicating data in the cookies, if I am following the code correctly

Comment: You also have a SCOPE issue in `logged_in()`!! `$mobile` and `$user` do not exists in the scope of the function !!!

Answer (score 0):

Swap line 2 and 3 to above the `session_start()`

```
<?php 
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1209600); 
// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(1209600);

session_start();
```